# Python Input string inside Webpage search

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python. I am trying to write a program that will take an IP address and use the search function on https://community.spiceworks.com/tools/ip-lookup/ to search that IP and return the results to me.

I wrote this:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://community.spiceworks.com/tools/ip-lookup/"
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
    search_box = browser.find_element_by_id("ipaddress")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    try:
        tables = browser.find_element_by_class("in-card detail-list ember-view")
    results = []
    for table in tables:
        print(table)
        results.append(table)
    browser.close()

    return results
    print(results)

get_results("137.2.167.117")
```

(I used a random IP address) When I run this, I get:

```
results = [] (with an arrow pointing to the "s" in results) SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I writing this code correctly? What is causing that error? And am I using the search function and results correctly? Searching this didn't return many results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As defined by the language a `try` block must be followed by an `except` or a `finally`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> try:
...    print("foo")
... results = []
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    results = []
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Your code fails for the same reason as the above snippet, the next statement (`results`) is neither a `except` or `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't time to try to run the code because I don't have the selenium library at the moment, but just pasting it into Pycharm highlights a couple of issues:

- you need to define the `except` for your `try`
- if the `try` fails, tables is not going to be defined and will cause issues when reading it in the for loop
- `print(results)` after the return will never be reached

What's causing the syntax error is the lack of `except`. A quick fix for the first two issues would be:

```
try:
    tables = browser.find_element_by_class("in-card detail-list ember-view")
except:
    tables = []
```